# Exchange API using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, json, algorithm, api

I'm using javascript to use the API on this site https://www.luno.com/en/api and I don't understand why I am not receiving any data. When if I just enter this url: https://api.mybitx.com/api/1/ticker?pair=XBTZAR I do receive data in the broswer.

```js
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    document.getElementById("luno").innerHTML = myObj.bid;
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://api.mybitx.com/api/1/ticker?pair=XBTZAR", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Why is it not returning anything?

Comment: What is the question? What can you not figure out? It is an object so you reference the key that you want to get the details for.

Comment: Neither one of my example codes work for either API and I don't understand why

Comment: Code works fine if you reference the properties the right way.... There is no "last" on that object. it is inside one of the other objects.

Comment: In the first block I don't know how to parse for just a pair like ETH_PLU and then use on of the objects inside

Comment: the api says it has a market parameter, if I append the market parameter like this https://api.idex.market/returnTicker?market=ETH_PLU it doesn't change anything

Comment: I figured it out. I should just use:  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj.ETH_PLU.last; to get the object inside the object.

Comment: But why isn't the luno one working even if I change the last to a bid?

Comment: Do you not see the big error in the console?

Comment: I do not know what the error means

Comment: CORS, means you can make the call from the browser. Plenty of discussions on it.

Comment: I'm reading about it now, so there is no simple line of code that will make the data available in my case?

Comment: it is literally this: xhr.setRequestHeader("CORS header", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin") but I don't know exactly what needs to be inside

Comment: You can not set CORS from JavaScript, the server has to set it. They have to give you permission to access it. The other one sets it, hence why it works.

Answer (score 1):

You have a trouble with [CORS](https://www.maxcdn.com/one/visual-glossary/cors/) requests.

You can see similar error on your developer console:
[image]

You can't call API from JS code because `api.mybitx.com` blocks cross domain request.

You have a several solutions:

1. Create own server side API method.
   Call this method from your JS code.
   Inside the API method call `api.mybitx.com` API using [WebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) or [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/).
2. If you want to do it only on JS code, then you need to use [EasyXDM](https://github.com/oyvindkinsey/easyXDM) library.

For me the first solution is more simpler and more correct.

Comment: I realise this is an old post, but I've gone an implemented a basic expressjs server with a reactjs app that calls on the LunoAPI, I hope it helps for anyone that might be having the same issue https://github.com/nicholasbergesen/luno-app